# C# Contains don't work's with "\"

Tags: c#, contains

Well, It's a noob question...

I'm trying to use:

```
if (string.Contains("\")) { return false; }
```

But I receive the message:

> Newline in constant

How I can use this method to detect "\" in a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\` character in a string is used to escape other characters - for example, `\n` is a newline character, and `\"` is the double quote character.

The way to get a `\` character is either to escape it (`"\\"`) or to preface the string with `@` so the compiler doesn't escape characters (`@"\"`).

Comment: It's a matter of preference.  Personally in this case I'd escape (`"\\"`) and only use `@` for longer or more confusing strings - file paths or regexes, etc.

Comment: I know you are going to fix the comment by editing it but I love the irony of your last comment.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It took me a little while to figure it out, too :)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that in C#, `\` is the escape character, thus `\"` is how you include a double quote in a string rather than terminate - note that the text turns "string" color *even in Stack Overflow*. In order to include the escape character, double-escape, thus:

```
if (string.Contains("\\")) { return false; }
```

Alternatively, string "literals" allow you to ignore any escape character short of double quote (which is escaped via inserting it twice)

```
if (string.Contains(@"\")) { return false; }
```

Comment: Good explanation with solid fall back examples

Answer (score 1):

YOu can do something like this

```
if (string.Contains("\\")) { return false; }
```